# Python remove leading whitespace error

Tags: python, regex, string

It looked simple, "remove whitespace from a string in the list". But for some reason, my code didn't work.

```
new_list = []
channels = "KMP, PRIME"
channel = channels.split(",")

for each in channel:
    re.sub(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*', ' ', each)
    new_list.append(each)
```

I also tried **lstrip/strip**, but none worked. Why?
If I "cheat" with the following code, it will work. I still want to get to the bottom of the problem. What should I change to make it right?

> channel = channels.split(", ")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using a list  comprehension and `str.strip`.

Note it does not appear you require regex for this task.

```
channels = 'KMP, PRIME'

lst = [i.strip() for i in channels.split(',')]
# ['KMP', 'PRIME']

res = ','.join(lst)
# KMP,PRIME
```

Answer (score 1):

From the ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)):

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by ...

You need to keep the value retuned by `.sub()`

```
for each in channel:
    new_list.append(re.sub(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*', ' ', each))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach too:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x.strip(),channels.split(','))))
```

output:

```
['KMP', 'PRIME']
```